# $('#form1:input') doesn't work

Tags: jquery

What if I have 2 forms on 1 page:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

And I want to access the input elements of the first one.  I do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bla = $('#form1:input');
    alert(bla.length);
});
```

But it displays 0 count.  I'll appreciate if somebody can advise.

---

Thank you.  The following syntax worked for me:

```
$('#form1 :input')
```

that is, putting the space.

Comment: `#form1:input` selects any form element with ID `form1`. It seems you want the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a space to your selector.

`#form1:input` means `#form1` **is** an `:input`

`#form1 :input` grabs an `:input` **within** `#form1`

---

When you combine selectors without a space or comma, you're saying "not only does it qualify as X, but as Y and Z. e.g.:

```
div.foo#bar
```

The above means it's a `<div>` element, that **also** has the `foo` class **and** has an ID of `bar`. e.g.
`<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>`

However:

```
div .foo .bar
```

The above means to look for a div that **contains** another element with the class `foo` which **also contains** another element with the class of `bar`. e.g.
`<div><p class="foo"><img class="bar" /></p></div>`

Answer (score 4):

`$("#form1 input").length` - the : is for special identifiers like :first

Comment: Incorrect -- http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ -- `:input` selects all form controls (including selects, buttons and textareas), while `input` selects only input tags.

Comment: `:input` selects all input type elements such as `<input>` `<select>` `<textarea>` while `input` only selects `<input>` elements. The real problem was the missing space in his selector.

Comment: Faster and more proper: `$( 'input', '#form1' )` (the second argument is the context - you don't want to query the entire page, but just the `#form1` element)

Comment: @mblase75 Based on what the user asked, this would solve the query.  They asked to select all of the `<input>` elements, not the `<input>`, `<radio>`, `<textarea>`, and `<checkbox>` elements.  The :input selector is best used after you filter out all elements as it cannot take advantage of native DOM methods.

Comment: @Whetstone You said (or at least implied) he needed to remove the colon. He did not need to remove the colon. Ergo, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @mblase75 Correct, as the colon would return the wrong set of elements.

Comment: What would fix the problem is adding the space between `#form1` and `:input` in his selector. Changing `:input` to `input` makes no difference in the provided code/html. In your answer you added the space AND changed from `:input` to `input`. Adding the space is what fixed it. Removing the colon neither fixed it nor broke it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Are you 100% positive about faster? jQuery uses a right-to-left selection method besides.

Comment: @KevinB Correct, in the sample code, both selectors would work.  In my answer, I was working under the assumption that this is sample code, and as such in the askers correct code they may have extra elements such as `<radio>` or `<checkbox>` that may not need to be selected.  Of course, this is an assumption, and if the asker wanted to get all elements that the user can change, `:input` would be more accurate.  I made the assumption based on the question "I want to access the input elements" rather than "I want to access the forms controls".

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, it's faster. See here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-with-tagname (that's not my test, I googled it). Right-to-left selection performs worse than left-to-right in the case of the selector `'#form1 input'` - that's my point.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this (you want the child of the form so don't put the colon)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bla = $('#form1 input');
    alert(bla.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong the selector do it like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var bla = $('#form1 input');
     alert(bla.length);
});
```

[here's a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/drhXG/)